# Can you use Array.map to get rid of the elements it acts on based on a condition?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I was wondering that, imagine I had an array like the following:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4]
```

Would it be possible to do something like:

```
arr.map(function(val, index, arr){
    if(val === 2){
       return; //I want to return nothing 
    } else {
       return val *2;
    }
});
```

Here is what I want to get:

```
[2,6,8]
```

What I actually get:

```
[2, undefined, 6, 8]
```

I know this behavior is the proper one, but I would like to know how I could achieve my desired result using map if possible. Essentially, I want the elements that don't return to be as if they never existed  in the array.

Comment: `Array.filter` on `undefined` afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could filter the array first and then map it.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];

arr = arr.filter(function(val) {
  return val !== 2;
}).map(function(val) {
  return val * 2;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 it's so easy and readable:

```
[1,2,3,4].filter(i => i !== 2).map(i => i * 2);
```